# How to change save and load dialogs on VSCode on Linux

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code

Since a recent update in VSCode for Ubuntu, when I open the "Save" or "Load" dialog, it opens but it is not focused. I have to search the dialog using alt+tab.

In the other hand, when I open VSCode on windows from Ubuntu WSL console and I try to save a file, it does not open an independent window, it opens an integrated save dialog as it is shown in the following image:

[image: Integrated vscode save dialog]

Is it posible to enable this behavior in VSCode for Ubuntu?

Thank you for your help